# Post/Redirect/Get Pattern in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, post-redirect-get

What is the best practice for implementing the Post/Redirect/Get pattern in ASP.NET MVC? In particular, what is the best way to do this when you want to redirect back to the initial action/controller?

Here's how I am currently doing this:

1. Display form to user.

   - In the form, use `<%= Html.Hidden("returnUrl") %>`
   - In the action, use `ViewData["returnUrl"] = Request.Url;`
2. User submits the form via POST
3. Redirect to the `returnUrl` model-binding, if not `null`. Otherwise, redirect to homepage.

This get's the job done, but it feels like this would result in a lot of duplication. I also realized that I could probably redirect to `Request.UrlReferrer`...

What do you suppose is the cleanest, most ideal method of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The way you're doing this is fine, but it looks like you might be overthinking it a little bit.  Do your POST actions take form posts from more than one form?  If not, why bother with a hidden form field?  You could get away with a simple `RedirectToAction("MyAction")`

Comment: Currently, I do not take form posts from more than one form - so I definitely see your point. In this particular case, I'll probably just use RedirectToAction. If, however, I did have more than one form, would you still suggest I do it via my current method?

Answer (score 4):

Typically, an action that handles a POST knows where it needs to redirect upon successful submission.  Therefore, each action that implements RGP can simply invoke `RedirectToAction(string)`.

```
public ViewResult Edit(string email)
{
  // save the email
  return RedirectToAction("Edit");
}
```