# Antiforgery token: how to change expiration time

Tags: asp.net-core, antiforgerytoken

I'm trying to add a token to a razor view which is being sent through an HTTP header (I'm following the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-3.1#javascript-ajax-and-spas)). Unfortunately, the default expiration timeout is different from the login session (120 mins vs 20, if I'm not mistaken).

So, is there a way to change the expiration time of the token? The options passed to the `AAddAntiforgery` method will let me setup the cookie lifetime, but what about the token? Do I need to change the session timeout?

Thanks

Comment: You can refer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15933707/11965297)

Answer (score 0):

After some digging, I've found the answer on the [official MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#data-protection). Besides settting the `Load User Profile` option to true, it's also required to make sure that the `setProfileEnvironment` is enabled (by default, it was set to false in the app pool default template on my Windows 10 dev machine).

Comment: Your shared document doesn't explain anything, which document you are referring to?

Comment: Seems like it stopped working. Here's another: https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/main/aspnetcore/host-and-deploy/iis/advanced.md