# Two login forms result in anti-forgery token exception

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

In my application sometimes i get the exception when I try to log in:

> A required anti-forgery token was not supplied or was invalid.

I can't reproduce it in 100%, but it happens frequently.

My **guess** is that is has something to do with multiple login forms on the same page.

More precisely:

- On top of my page there is a small log in/out panel always visible.
- If the unauthorized user tries an action he's not supposed to, he gets redirected to a dedicated log in page.
- Than there are 2 different forms pointing to the same action.
- Both forms have:

  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
- The log in action is decorated with:

  [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]

My questions:

1. Can this be the problem?
2. If not, than what can it be?
3. And of course how to fix it?

Please note that:

- This top log in/out panel is in a partial, which is in a partial ... which is in the _Layout.cshtml
- The dedicated log in page is rendered as a body.

Comment: Have you looked at this SO question about troubleshooting [anti-forgery tokens](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767768/troubleshooting-anti-forgery-token-problems)?

Comment: Why not just not display the top login bar on the dedicated login page as a test?

Comment: @Tommy it would be inconclusive as like I said I can't reproduce it 100% actually it happens in like 20% of the log in attempts.

Comment: @gisek - are you sure that this is the page that is causing it?  I have found that expired logins can sometimes create bad anti-forgery request as well (if the login cookie expired) or if you do not have your machine key set to a static key (meaning set to auto-generate)

Comment: @Tommy I'm not sure of anything here actually :) We can exclude login cookie expiration as it occured on machines that visited the page for the first time. My machine key is static - set in Web.config

Comment: It has something to do with cookies. The server checks 2 tokens: 1 from cookeis and 1 from the psoted form. Apparently they don't match.