# Save button executes a random number of ajax calls

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

As the title says I have a problem with a save button which saves many times. Sometimes it works as it should and sometimes saves 2,3,5,13 times. The number is different everytime.

> Some parts of the code will be hidden for copyright reasons. Sorry ;(

At first I thought it could be my mouse clicking more than once on the button so I added the following code to the jquery that calls the method in the Controller:

```
@(vm).saveobject= function() {
     $("#savebutton").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
     var url = //Some valid Url      

     var entity = {//code here
     };

     $.ajax({
         url: url,
         type: 'post',
         contentType: 'application/json',
         dataType: 'json',
         data: JSON.stringify(entity),
         success: function (resultado) {
             var result = resultado.result.toString();
             if (result.toLowerCase() == "true".toLowerCase()) {
                 $('#Grid').data("tGrid").rebind()
                 alert("Blablabla");
             } else {
                 alert(resultado.error);
             }
         }
     });
     $("#saveButton").removeAttr('disabled');
 };
```

Code of the controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public virtual JsonResult Save(Onject o)
    {
        string error = string.Empty;
        if (//Conditions)
        {
            Repository.SaveOrUpdate(o);
            return Json(new { result = true ,error = error}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else {
            error = "Blablablabla";
            return Json(new { result = false, error = error }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

But that didn't work. I read the following question [How do I prevent multiple form submission in .NET MVC without using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250604/how-do-i-prevent-multiple-form-submission-in-net-mvc-without-using-javascript) but I don't know if might be helpful as the method already implements [HttpPost]

Do you have any idea?

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Move the `$("#saveButton").removeAttr('disabled');` statement in the `success` or better in `complete` callback of ajax.

Comment: Are you sure that it makes multiple ajax calls ? Did you open the browser console/network tab to confirm this ? Or is it a problem with your Repository.SaveOrUpdate method ?

Comment: @Shyju Hi. I am sure it calls the method more than once.