# Preventing duplicate inserts into database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a page of announcements that when a user views it, adds it to a "seen" database. The issue with this is, if I user then clicks the same page twice then it records that twice and so on. Here is my code, How could I check if the entry already exists in the database?

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    string currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    var currentUser = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == currentUserId);

    List<Seen> seens = new List<Seen>();  

    foreach (Announcement anoun in db.Announcements)
    {
        seens.Add(new Seen
                      {
                          User = currentUser, // You have this already so why go to the database again?
                          Announcement = anoun, // Same with this.
                      });
    }

    db.Seens.AddRange(seens);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return View(db.Announcements.ToList());
}
```

Comment: You just add to the DB, where is your code to check if it already exists in DB?

Comment: @L.B thats what the question is

Comment: So you want someone write it for you? Where is your effort?

Answer (score 1):

There are several things to consider:

1) **database integrity** - consider adding UNIQUE constraints as a safety net for business uniqueness - in your case (SeenId, UserId) or something similar. This will also add an index that makes some selections faster.

2) **prevent double submit** - first point prevents persistence of duplicates, but will also lead to error. In order to avoid this, you should take a look upon [preventing double submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250604/how-do-i-prevent-multiple-form-submission-in-net-mvc-without-using-javascript).

In MVC, a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120882/post-redirect-get-pattern-in-asp-net-mvc) dealing with preventing double submission shows how Post/Redirect/Get Pattern is implemented in MVC.

Answer (score 0):

> How could I check if the entry already exists in the database?

well , you could simply set your SQL field to **Unique** to prevent multi entry of data , As I assume that you are working on a social network type of app and you want each user to be able to "view" your post/page only once.

another way is to use the same loop to search for the value in the field , and if it is there then it it just quits the process.

Answer (score 0):

There is some ways you can prevent it.

- Set your value as primary key in your database/table (uniqueness)
- Check for existing value in your code behind before inserting into DB (redirect or return message if exist)
- Disable submission button in client side page just after first click